# How do I scale the background image in this parallax for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to setup a fluid template that I can use for responsive design viewports too. However now when I try to resize my browser window it does not scale and on my iphone i just see the top left part of my header graphic. On mobile devices, the background images are extremely large and blurry, but they look fine on my [test website](http://www.artfbla.org). Any help would be greatly appreciated

CSS

```
/* ============================================================
  SECTIONS
============================================================ */
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;

}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;

}

.contentbg {
      background-color: rgba(230,230,230,.6);

}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 73vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width:100%;

}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image:url(../../images/5.jpg);
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image:url(../../images/6.jpg);
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image:url(../../images/4.jpg);
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {

  section.module h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
  section.module p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add the background-size: 100% auto , so you make your responsive according the screen resolution

```
section.module.parallax {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  max-width:100%;

}
```

Comment: I tried that yet it still does not work, anything else?

Answer (score -1):

Use responsive design from bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive
This will get you started.